# Distribution of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have continuous random variable $X$ with distribution $f_X$. That is

$$ P\left(a \le X \le b \right) = \int_{a}^{b} f_X(x) \ dx $$

Now suppose I have a function $\phi: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ 
How does one compute the distribution of $\phi(x)$? That is I want to find a $g(x)$ such that

$$ P \left( a \le \phi(X) \le b \right) = \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx $$

### My Work

Something to note is if $\phi$ is invertible and has the property that $a \le b \rightarrow \phi(a) \le \phi(b)$ then

$$ P(a \le \phi(X) \le b) = P(\phi^{-1}(a) \le X \le \phi^{-1}(b)) = \int_{\phi^{-1}{a}}^{\phi^{-1}{b}}f_X(x)  \ dx $$

Now with the substitution $u = \phi(x)$ we find that

$$ P(a \le \phi(x) \le b) = \int_{a}^{b} f_X(\phi^{-1}(u)) \frac{d \phi^{-1}(u)}{d \phi} \ du $$

so $g(x) = f_X(\phi^{-1}(x))  \frac{d \phi^{-1}(x)}{dx}$

Of course for $\phi(x)$ that don't satisfy this property we need to make modifications.

Consider for example: $X  \ \text{~} \ N(0,1)$, then we predict from above that

$$ g(x) =  f_X(\phi^{-1}(x))  \frac{d \phi^{-1}(x)}{dx} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}e^{- \frac{x}{2}}$$

Yet recalling that

$$ P \left( a \le X^2 \le b \right) =P \left( \sqrt{a} \le X \le \sqrt{b} \right)+ P \left( -\sqrt{b} \le X \le -\sqrt{a}  \right) $$

We see that

$$ g(x) =  -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}e^{- \frac{x}{2}} $$

(So we we were off by a factor of two)

In general depending on how badly uninvertible $\phi(x)$ is, we may be off by a larger factor. How to deal with this and create general formula for all $\phi(x)$

Comment: You can 1. Break up $\phi$ into regions of monotonicity and then recombine 2. Compute $g(y) = \sum_{x:\phi(x)=y}\frac{f_X(x)}{\phi'(x)}$ where possible.

Comment: Note that one needs an absolute value around $\phi'(x)$ in general case.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why the absolute value is necessary, please enlighten me :)

Comment: Because density is a positive quantity and $\phi'$ can be negative ($=-id$ for example). Hence you have an extraneous minus sign in your result for $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *as you noted*, when $\phi$ is not invertable we have to modify the *transformation function*.

Such as, for instance, when $\phi(x)=x^2$, which is a *fold* mapping two intervals into one (the negative reals and non-negative reals to the non-negative reals), we modify the transformation formula to account for the fact that we have two "inverse" functions:   $\psi_1(x) = {+\sqrt{x}}~\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)}\\\psi_2(x) = {-\sqrt{x}}~\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)}$

Thusly:
$$\begin{align}
g(x) 
& =  f_X(\psi_1(x)) \left\lvert \frac{\mathsf d~\psi_1(x)}{\mathsf d~x}\right\rvert + f_X(\psi_2(x)) \left\lvert \frac{\mathsf d~\psi_2(x)}{\mathsf d~x}\right\rvert
\\[1.5ex] & =  f_X(\sqrt x) \left\lvert \frac{\mathsf d~\sqrt x}{\mathsf d~x}\right\rvert~\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)} + f_X(-\sqrt x) \left\lvert \frac{\mathsf d~(-\sqrt x)}{\mathsf d~x}\right\rvert~\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)}
\end{align}$$