# Functional Equation of Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, functional-equations

Suppose you have a real random variable $X$ that has probability distribution $f_X$ meaning

$$ P(\alpha \le X \le \beta) = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f_X(x) \  dx $$

Now assume $\Phi(f_X)$  is also a probability distribution where $\Phi$ is some function-of-functions of $f_X$. How does one find a $Q$ such that $Q(x)$ is a random variable with distribution $\Phi(f_X)$?

Now in here: [Distribution of a function of a random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641419/distribution-of-a-function-of-a-random-variable)

I had learned that if $Q(x)$ is invertible (will consider non-invertible case later) then the distribution of $Q(x)$ is

$$ f_X(Q^{-1}(x))\left| \frac{1}{Q'(Q^{-1}(x))} \right|  $$

So to find such a $Q$ we simply have to solve:

$$ f_X(Q^{-1}(x))\left| \frac{1}{Q'(Q^{-1}(x))} \right|  =  \Phi(f_X)$$

I don't suspect this is easily solvable. But perhaps someone has done research on these types of equations, would anyone be able to point to a source, and then I can descend into my own rabbit hole from there.

Comment: Billingsley's book Probability and Measure might be a good source.

Comment: If $F_X$ is continuous, then $U\sim F_X(X)$ and hence $\Phi^{-1}(F_X(X))$ has cdf $\Phi$.